# code deployment via zipped file in jenkins

Tags: apache, jenkins, plugins, deployment, server

I am new to Jenkins and still taking baby steps to learn it. What I have could be very simple to some people but I couldn't find a straightforward way to do it. I simply want to take source code in a zipped file format and do the following:

1. copy to remote server in a certain directoy
2. delete the old code
3. unzip the new code
4. delete the zipped file
5. finally start apache web server

I have installed plugins like ssh2, ssh-copy, remote commands, etc but still cannot achieve what I am looking in to do. Any help would greatly appreciated it.

Comment: Can you show an example of what did you tried ?  
You can also wrap everything into a `sh` block it will do the job.

Comment: I first need to know how can I import the zip file into jenkins tool and then I can create a freestyle job that can have those 4 commands I listed as shell commands steps. I am not sure if there is a plugin that allows zipped files to be imported.

Comment: Where is the zip coming from ? Should it be an input of the job or a download from somewhere ?

Comment: Zip file is coming from my desktop.

Comment: Have a look to : https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

I have a Spring project and build it to get a `.war` file by Jenkins.
The following shell commands show how to copy the `.war` to a remote server and to run it on Tomcat.

```sh
remote_host=192.168.1.2
tomcat_home=/x/y

# stop web server
ssh root@${remote_host} "sh /root/stop.sh" || echo "something wrong ignored!"

# copy to remote server in a certain directoy
scp $WORKSPACE/build/libs/myapp-test.war root@${remote_host}:$tomcat_home/webapps/myapp.war

# delete the old code
ssh root@${remote_host} "rm -rf $tomcat_home/webapps/*"

# unzip the new code
ssh root@${remote_host} "unzip -o $tomcat_home/webapps/myapp.war -d $tomcat_home/webapps/myapp"

# delete the zipped file
ssh root@${remote_host} "rm -rf $tomcat_home/webapps/myapp.war"

# finally start apache web server
ssh root@${remote_host} "sh $tomcat_home/bin/startup.sh"
```

In my case, I put the commands in a Jenkins job and at the section: Build -- Execute shell -- Command

Comment: Thanks Peter for your detailed answer. The problem is -- if I have to put a zip file on the server itself, than I can just scp that zip file over from my desktop and run set up of commands to deploy that code in a script (which is what I am doing right now) but with Jenkins, I looked at that option of code and excute with shell commands but first thing first how can I import the zipped file onto jenkins and secondly I would have to either create a user on the server itself to create ssh keys for it as this is on amazon ec2 instance and using traditional user/pass is not an option.

Comment: @geek12 I think you are having two questions. The first one is how to import the zip file into Jenkins. There are two ways: 1) if you can only scp zip from your desktop, you should make your pc as a Jenkins's slave node first, then Jenkins job can handle the file; 2) if you can compress, compile or other ways to create the zip file on an already existed slave node, just do it. The second question is about amazon ec2, I'm sorry to say that I have little experience on it.